# Динамическое добавление редюсера в стор | React | Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Можно ли как-то добавить редюсер в стор в ходе выполнения программы? Я хочу задействовать компонент из другого проекта, но ему трубуется стор с нужными редюсерами.
Можно ли как-то их динамично добавить в стор?

**(В проекте человек 20 и для каждого нового компонента повторять эти шаги не хочется)**

**(Не предлагайте передавать параметры через пропсы, меня интересует именно диническое раширение текущего стора дополнительными редюcерами)**

Comment: Если используется другой компонент, почему нельзя сразу написать под него редюсер? Или компонент тоже динамический? Теоретически я думаю что это возможно, но сопряжено с некоторым количеством минусов которые могут перевесить, я не совсем понял замысел того как будет происходить компановка.

Comment: @DaniilLoban, компоненты подтягиваются из другого проекта (сторибук). У них нет доступа к редюсеру, который создается внутри второго проекта (куда я импортирую).

Comment: Вот ссылка на документацию по этой теме с примером кода как делать связь, надеюсь это то что нужно https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/intro-to-storybook/react/en/data/